# Including count of a result in the main query?

Tags: sql-server, count

Currently, we execute two queries to get the count and the result with a pagination filter. While we can easily combine these into a single network call (using SQL separators), is there a way to do this in a single query following the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle? It is also challenging maintain both queries - single query reduces the overhead.

```sql
-- count    
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;

-- result with pagination
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tbl.idn) AS row, * FROM tbl)_tbl
WHERE row >= 1 AND row <= 10;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try create a stored procedure and call it from the application.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPage] 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cnt INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)

    SELECT *, [cnt] = @cnt
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tbl.idn) AS row, * FROM tbl)_tbl
    WHERE row >= 1 AND row <= 10;
END
```

Or you can use subquery:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPage] 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *, [cnt] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tbl.idn) AS row, * FROM tbl)_tbl
    WHERE row >= 1 AND row <= 10;
END
```

**Edit.**

Even better you can use `OFFSET FETCH` clause for paging puprose. You will get much cleaner code and higher performance (no window function here). For example somthing like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPage] 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cnt INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)

    SELECT *, [cnt] = @cnt
    FROM tbl
    ORDER BY idn
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
END
```

Or with subquery:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPage] 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *, [cnt] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)
    FROM tbl
    ORDER BY idn
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
END
```

There is no significant diffrence between a subquery and a variable approach. It's more about the notation. SQL Server does almost the same work (additional "nocost" Nested Loop). In this particular sitiation I prefer to avoid window function (possible Table Spool - additional impact on tempdb).